# App store doesn't show rating of my app

Tags: ios-appstore, itunes-store, app-store-connect, ratings

I have an app that has 23 ratings and 4,5 stars but if you search for the app they don't appear. If you tap on the app after searching for it, the stars appear but empty. You can only see the stars if you tap on Ratings.
It's not a problem of time, the app was released in July 2013 there are ratings from that time too.![image][image]

I'm on the Spanish App Store, and looking through the categories and there are many apps that have this same problem, only few apps have the 5 star rating under their name.

So what are we doing wrong? I would assume the ratings would appear automatically.

Comment: Practically - if you opened a support ticket with the iOS store support, you might get a better answer than we have on the site presently. I'll also post this to chat to see if we perhaps want to edit/reopen this if we can document differential behavior based on what country has an app for sale.